# Background Image doesnt show in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

[image]

So I have this in nodes but then in render, it stay grey. I hope someone knows whats the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should enable transparency in Render settings:

*Render Properties → Film → Transparent*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The *Background Images* option in the camera settings is for adding reference images in the *3D Viewport*, for example to position objects correctly if you are planning to *Alpha Over* the render in the *Compositor* as you tried to. They will not be rendered.

The reason the background stays grey in render is that 1. (as said before) the reference background image will not be rendered and 2. the *World* background is not considered transparent by default. To use *Alpha Over* in the compositor, the background behind the object has to be transparent. To make the *World* transparent, go to *Render Properties* > *Film* > *Transparent* and enable it.

[image: film transparent]